# SQL Select statement with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to run a little report on a existing cart to show me the open cart with products per user

so I have 3 tables I'm using:

```
orders
    id
    order_id
    user_id
    state
    customer_email
    customer_firstname
    customer_lastname

order_items
    id
    cms_id
    order_id
    name
    price

users
    id
    cms_id
    email
```

Cart is a status in the order table. If state = cart then the order still open.
I got to the point where I can show the customers and orders but I would like to also show the items in the orders

the relationship is:

user has many orders
orders has many items

users.id = orders.user_id

Here is my query:

```
select 
    users.email AS user_email, 
    orders.customer_email AS order_email,
    orders.customer_firstname,
    orders.customer_lastname,
    orders.state
from 
    users, 
    orders 
where 
    users.id = orders.user_id and orders.state = "cart"
```

**EDIT:** For more understating of what I'm trying to do

I want to return ALL orders that have the state set as "cart". Within those orders I want to return all the items in them

Now that I have all the Orders/cart with the items in them I want to see the users if there is no user (in case they are logged out) it can show blank... I still wanna see that cart

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @popovitsj I need to add order_items into that query. I had tried something similar to the answer below but all the ANDs end up returning nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select 
    users.email AS user_email, 
    orders.customer_email AS order_email,
    orders.customer_firstname,
    orders.customer_lastname,
    orders.state
from 
    users join  orders on users.id = orders.user_id
    join order_items on orders.order_id = order_items.order_id
where 
   orders.state = "cart"

Comment: I picked this option because I ended up using the left join to return all the values from the order table

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    users.email AS user_email, 
    orders.customer_email AS order_email,
    orders.customer_firstname,
    orders.customer_lastname,
    orders.state,
    order_items.name,
    order_items.price
from 
    users, 
    orders,
    order_items 
where 
    users.id = orders.user_id and 
    orders.order_id = order_items.order_id and
    orders.state = "cart"
```

Comment: I had tried something similar but all the ANDs in the where statements makes the query to selective and it return nothing. I was wondering if I should use joins intead of the ands

Comment: If you're not getting any rows it's because the data in the tables is not matching up. I also note that it's a bit odd to have both order.id and order.order_id : do they have the same value? If not then which one relates to the rows in the order_items table?